# Linq to Entities without generic parameter

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

If this is a property implementation where `Context` is an Entity Framework `DbContext` and `Tours` is a `DbSet`...

```
public IQueryable ListQuery => Context.Tours;
```

... then the calling code has limited ability to continue the query. For example, I can't even call `ToList()` on the result.

How do I return an un-typed query, such that I can do things like `Take` and `Skip` on the result, without the calling code knowing what the type is?

I don't want the type to leak out of the interface, because then my data access code is tied to one EF model in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cast the result to `IQueryable<object>`. I'm not sure why that's allowable. Is it because its covariant?